# accessing variable of one function in another in ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

> im trying to create a progress bar using ajax, here is the html code:

```
  <BODY onload='process();move()'>
    <div id='myProgress'>
     <div id='progress-bar'>
     </div>
    </div>
    <br><p> progress bar <A id='percent'></A></p><br>
    STATUS = <A id='runtime'></A>
    </BODY>
```

> here is the ajax code:

```
function handleServerResponse()
{
 if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
{
   xmlResponse=xmlHttp.responseXML;
    xmldoc = xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName('response');
   message = xmldoc[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
   document.getElementById('runtime').innerHTML=message;
 }
 }
```

> here is the javascript code for progress bar:

```
function move()
 {
   elem = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
   width = message;
   elem.style.width = width + '%';
   document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = width;
  }
```

> im having trouble accessing 'message' variable in javascript I need
>   help.

Comment: post error / output from wat u have tried

Comment: call `move` from  `handleServerResponse` after you get `message`

Comment: @tharif im getting undefined value at progress bar (id='percent')

Comment: @FastSnail how should i call move(), just simply????

Comment: @ArunSubba yes just after the `message = xmldoc[0].firstChild.nodeValue;` line.but remove `move()` from onload

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: its working now